# Horizontal sharp background gradient with specific length of first color

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I've seen vertical columns created in pure CSS with something like this:

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #a2ea4c 200px, #07aa91 200px, #07aa91);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Is it possible to make a **horizontal header of a fixed size** in a similar manner as the above i.e. using only CSS?

** EDIT **

The below is a minimal example of what I'm trying to do. I wan't to set the background gradient on the html tag in order to have different overscroll colors on the top and bottom of the page, with variable, sometimes transparent content in the middle. When using variable content to fill up the page, the gradient fills the page completely with the first color. As in the below example.

```css
html {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a2ea4c 200px, #07aa91 200px, #07aa91);
}

div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p> Lorem ipsum sit amet</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

(If you switch the p-tag for a div-tag, you'll see that the gradient works as expected)

Comment: Didn't quite understand the question. What is wrong with the current snippet? The first color is already of fixed length. Are you saying that you want them as rows instead of columns?

Comment: That's exactly it. :) The example shows a vertical column, I want a horizontal header. That is, I want to turn the whole example 90 degrees clockwise.

Comment: You mean something like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/178/?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first parameter to the `linear-gradient` function is the direction in which the gradient should be applied. In the snippet in question, it is `to right` and so the output looks like columns. To change it to look like rows, just change the direction to `to bottom` like in the below snippet.

You can read more about `linear-gradient` and its arguments [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a2ea4c 200px, #07aa91 200px, #07aa91);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Below is an explanation of the gradient itself for better understanding:

- The gradient is a `linear-gradient`, that is, the colors change linearly in straight lines.
- The direction is `to bottom` which means that the `0%` (or `0px`) is at the top of the container and `100%` is at the bottom of the container.
- `#a2ea4c 200px` indicates that the gradient would have the color as `#a2ea4c` till the `200px` mark from top.
- `#07aa91 200px` indicates that at the `200px` mark, the gradient's color **suddenly changes** from `#a2ea4c` to `#07aa91`. This makes it a **hard-stop** gradient as there is no gradual color change.
- `#07aa91` means that the color stays the same from the `200px` mark till the end of the gradient.

---

The gradient that is provided in the second snippet is not being visible due to the following reasons:

- The gradient has color as `#a2ea4c` only for the first 200px but the `p` element's height is 300px.
- The `p` tag is by default a block level container and when there is no special CSS styling, it takes 100% width.
- So effectively, the `p` tag covers the entire area of the gradient that has a different color.

If you replace the `p` tag with `div` (and thereby result in your custom CSS get applied), the gradient would be visible because the `width` then becomes only 20%.

```css
html {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a2ea4c 200px, #07aa91 200px, #07aa91);
}
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum sit amet</div>
```

Comment: You are exactly right. However, when I tried that very solution on my own code it still didn't work. I'll try and update with a better example of my situation.

Comment: I've updated the question with a better description and example code.

Comment: @DanielStröm: Ok, you don't see the gradient because it is covered by the `div` element's background. Its height is 300px and the gradient has a different color only for the first 200px.

Comment: Really? But why would the p-tag take up the full width and height of the page?

Comment: @DanielStröm: `p` is not taking up full height. It is just covering the first 200px (which is the part of the gradient which has a different color). Plus, the `p` by default takes 100% width (as it is a block element). If you change it to `div` then the gradient should be visible behind.